# Angular2: How to get a reference to a component using Javascript in the browser console

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, protractor

In an Angular2 app, how do I access a component's controller from the browser console, using Javascript?

I am trying to invoke a method from a service used by my component.

**EDIT**: My intent is to invoke it from within Protractor tests.

From what I've read [here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/), I should be able to get a reference to the instance of my component class by using `ng.probe($0).componentInstance`, but I am getting `null`.

Comment: What do you want to do, actually?

Comment: `$0` refers to the element you've selected inside the elements tab of chrome, make sure you've got an Angular Component selected within the elements tab

Comment: @maddockst - Thanks! Now it makes sense and works :)

Comment: I made an edit about how I want to use it eventually - protractor tests in order to simulate certain changes in the service (mock data changing)

Comment: Maybe try storing the reference to the component in a globally accessible variable? You could initialize that variable in the component's constructor, for example.